# Apache httpd.conf - Virtual hosts port

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, centos, webserver

I have an **Apache** Webserver running, which is reachable over the ip/port-combination `123.456.789:9000` from my browser.

Also I have a **GitLab** instance running on the ip/port-combination `123.456.789:8888` and a GitLab module named **KanBan** on `123.456.789:8889`.

If someone requests the website `123.456.789:9000/gitlab` I want the **Apache** Webserver to route the request to `123.456.789:8888`.

Respectively If someone requests `123.456.789:9000/kanban` I want the **Apache** Webserver route to `123.456.789:8889`.

So instead of opening the ports 8888 and 8889 directly I want the Apache Webserver to function as a tunnel, which binds the two adresses to different ports internally while the ip remains the same.

I read that this kind of configuration is done inside httpd.conf and involses adding so called virtual hosts therein. Also it could involve some Linux specific routing via `bind` command.

Is this correct and if so can someone point me in the right direction of how to adpat the **httpd.conf** file?

If this is not possible how could I nevertheless configure it on my **CentOs 7.1** Server?

EDIT-1:
Before cross-posting this on https://serverfault.com/ could an Administrator/Mod do it?

EDIT-2:
I have found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port and it looks like its the same use case, but i am still trying it out.

EDIT-3:
After checking in with people in the IRC Channel #httpd, I was told that Apache Reverse Proxies should do the trick and was given this resource, http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies, which i am currently working on.

Comment: "**Before cross-posting**". Don't do this. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: I mean not the Admin should cross-post it. I meant that he migrates it to serverfault.com...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a simple httpd configuration, a neat way to implement what you are looking for would be:

- Create a file named `/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitlab.conf` with the contents:

  ```
  ProxyPass "/gitlab" "http://123.456.789:8888"
  ProxyPassReverse "/gitlab" "http://123.456.789:8888"
  ```
- Create another file named `/etc/httpd/conf.d/kanban.conf` with the contents:

  ```
  ProxyPass "/kanban" "http://123.456.789:8889"
  ProxyPassReverse "/kanban" "http://123.456.789:8889"
  ```
- Restart httpd.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I browse to `http://213.95.228.155:9000/tomcat` and see `Service Unavailable - The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`